# Hebrews 1:6 "Proskuneo" & Psalm 2:12 "Kiss the son"

Tags: hebrew, psalms

I studied trough The Book of Hebrews chapter 1 and found the word worship **προσκυνησ** proskyneō literal means ""to kiss and was immediately thinking of Psalm 2:12 "Kiss the Son"

(Hebrew 1:6 KJV) - And again, when he bringeth in the firstbegotten into the world, he saith, And let all the angels of God **worship** him Ὅταν δὲ πάλιν εἰσαγάγῃ τὸν πρωτότοκον εἰς τὴν οἰκουμένην λέγει Καὶ **προσκυνησάτωσαν** αὐτῷ πάντες ἄγγελοι Θεοῦ

(Psalm 2:12 KJV) - "**Kiss the Son**, lest he be angry, and ye perish from the way, when his wrath is kindled but a little. Blessed are all they that put their trust in him."

1: Is Psalm 2:12 "Kiss the son" referring to worship as to say "worship the son"
2: Is Hebrews 1:6 correctly interpret as to mean; "all the angels of God worship him"

Comment: You ought to include the passage from where the quote actually originated from. *“Rejoice with him, O heavens; **bow down προσκυνησατωσαν  to him, all gods**, for he avenges the blood of his children and takes vengeance on his adversaries. He repays those who hate him and cleanses his people’s land.””
‭‭Deuteronomy‬ ‭32:43‬*

Comment: @Daniel Dahlberg The same Greek word for worship "proskuneo" is also used at Matthew 4:10 and at Luke 4:8 by Jesus when He says, "It is written, You shall worship the Lord you God and serve Him only." This word in both context means actually "worshiping" and not simply obeisance  or bowing down in respect as some groups believe.

Comment: @Mr.Bond I have been in a discussion with a JW member regarding Heb 1:6 worship/obeisance. Thanks for the verses (Matthew 4:10 & Luke 4:10) in NWT has this translated worship only when it comes to Jesus they are fast to change that obeisance. God bless!

Comment: @NihilSineDeo I did not know about Deu32:43 LXX thank you very much it was good indeed and fits perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a thorn in the side of those who hold some minority views of Deity.  The OP raises several matters that must be dealt with separately.

**Psalm 2:12**

In understanding Heb 1:6, Ps 2:12 is not germane because it is NOT quoted.  Instead, Heb 1:6 is alluding to Deut 32:43 - (especially the LXX).

> Rejoice, O heavens, with Him, and let all God’s angels worship Him.

Concerning the contentious meaning of Ps 2:12, "kiss the son" - see appendix below.

**προσκυνέω (proskuneó)**

According to BDAG, the single meaning of this word in the NT is:

> **to express in attitude or gesture one's complete dependence on or submission to a high authority figure, *(fall down and) worship, do
> obeisance to, prostrate oneself before, do reverence to, welcome
> respectfully***

Interestingly, when this was done by a human toward anything other than God, it was immediately stopped as highly inappropriate/illegal/sinful:

- Acts 10:25 - Cornelius to Peter
- Rev 19:10a - John to the angel
- Rev 22:8 - John to the angel
- Acts 7:43 - idol worship
- Matt 4:9, Luke 4:7 - Jesus to the Devil/Satan
- Rev 9:20 - idol worship
- Rev 13:4, 8, 12, 13:15, 16:2, etc - beast worship

By contrast with the above, worship (proskuneó) of Jesus is never rejected: Matt 2:2, 8, 11, 8:2, 9:18, 14:33, 15:25, 20:20, 28:19, 17, Mark 5:6, 15:19, Luke 24:52, John 9:38, etc.

Thus, it is entirely appropriate to translate προσκυνέω (proskuneó) in Heb 1:6 as "worship" as almost every version does such as: NIV, NLT, ESV, BSB, BLB, KJV, NKJV, NASB, CSB, HCSB, ASV, CEV, ERV, GNT, ISV, LSV, NET, Weymouth, WEB, etc.

**APPENDIX - "Kiss the Son"** (Ps 2:12)

Most commentators do not like this translation; Ellicott is typical -

> **(12) Kiss the Son**.—This familiar translation must be surrendered. It has against it the weight of all the ancient versions except the
> Syriac. Thus the Chaldaic has, “receive instruction “; LXX., followed
> by Vulg., “lay hold of discipline.” Symmachus and Jerome render “pay
> pure adoration.”Aquila has “kiss with discernment.” Bar, in the sense
> of “son,” is common in Chaldee, and is familiar to us from the Aramaic
> patronymics of the New Testament: e.g., Bar-Jonas, Bar-nabas, &c. The
> only place where it occurs in Heb., is Proverbs 31:2, where it is
> repeated three times; but the Book of Proverbs has a great deal of
> Aramaic colouring. Our psalmist uses ben for “son” in Psalm 2:7, and
> it is unlikely that he would change to so unusual a term, unless
> nashshekû-bar were a proverbial saying, and of this there is no proof
> Surely, too, the article or a suffix would have been employed. “Kiss
> son” seems altogether too abrupt and bald even for Hebrew poetry. The
> change of subject also in the co-ordinate clause, “lest he (i.e.,
> Jehovah, as the context shows) be angry,” is very awkward. As to the
> translation of the verb, the remark of Delitzsch, that it means “to
> kiss, and nothing else,” is wide of the mark, since it must in any
> case be taken figuratively, with sense of doing homage, as in Genesis
> 41:40 (margin), or worshipping (1Kings 19:18; Hosea 13:2). The most
> consistent rendering is, therefore, proffer pure homage (to Jehovah),
> lest he be angry. It may be added that the current of Rabbinical
> authority is against our Authorised version. Thus R. Solomon: “Arm
> yourselves with discipline;” (so, with a slight variation, one of the
> latest commentators, E. Reuss: “Arm yourselves with loyalty”;) another
> Rabbi: “Kiss the covenant”; another, “Adore the corn.” Among the best
> of modern scholars, Hupfeld renders “yield sincerely”; Ewald, “receive
> wholesome warning”; Hitzig, “submit to duty”; Gratz (by emendation),
> “give good heed to the warning.”

See the Cambridge commentary for a more extensive survey and discussion.